# Trying to translate C program to reverse a number into x86 assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, att

I'm trying to translate the following program to x86 assembly ( AT&T ).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int n = 123;
   int reverse = 0;


   while (n != 0)
   {
      reverse = reverse * 10;
      reverse = reverse + n%10;
      n       = n/10;
   }

   printf("%d\n", reverse);

   return 0;
}
```

It's supposed to print 321.

However, with the code below, I'm getting a 0 instead.
Can anybody give me a clue about what I'm doing wrong here?
( I pasted just the relevant section below. I'm sure that initialization and printing are working fine. You can see [the whole thing here](https://gist.github.com/ruanchaves/b0caf393edf0637add2ef7f0f543b55b))

```
  movl  $123, %esi    # int n
  movl  $0, %edi    # int reverse
  movl $10, %ebx    # divisor


L1:     # while n != 0

cmpl $0, %esi
je L2

# reverse = reverse * 10
imul $10, %edi

# reverse = reverse + n % 10
movl $0, %edx
movl %edi, %eax
idivl %ebx
addl %edx, %edi

# n = n / 10
movl %esi, %eax
movl $0, %edx
idivl %ebx
movl %eax, %esi

jmp L1

L2:  # end while

movl %edi, %eax
```

Maybe I'm not yet perfectly understanding what the idivl command is supposed to do. I understand that it divides %edx:%eax by %ebx and stores the quotient in %eax and the remainder in %edx.

Comment: Yes, that's how `idivl` works. Use your debugger to single step the code and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: A refreshing well posted question.

Comment: One `idiv` gives you both quotient and remainder; you don't need to run it twice with the same inputs.  (Oh, I think this was actually your bug; *not* using the same inputs even though you want `n/10` and `n%10`.)

Comment: Notice that you can use `xor %reg, %reg` to set a register to 0, which will be faster than doing `movl $0, %reg`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# reverse = reverse + n % 10
movl $0, %edx
movl %edi, %eax   ; <--- here
```

`%edi` is not `n`, according to the comments above:

```
movl  $123, %esi    # int n
```

So, it should be using `%esi`, i.e. `movl %esi, %eax`.

Comment: That was the only thing missing. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes it is good to see what the compiler generates

```
int reverse(int x)
{
   int r = 0;

   while (x != 0)
   {
      r = r * 10;
      r = r + x%10;
      x = x/10;
   }
   return r;
}
```

and shortest version:

```
reverse:
  xor eax, eax
  mov esi, 10
.L2:
  test edi, edi
  je .L5
  imul ecx, eax, 10
  mov eax, edi
  cdq
  idiv esi
  mov edi, eax
  lea eax, [rdx+rcx]
  jmp .L2
.L5:
  ret
```

or the fastest:

```
reverse:
  xor eax, eax
  test edi, edi
  je .L4
  mov esi, 1717986919
.L3:
  lea ecx, [rax+rax*4]
  mov eax, edi
  imul esi
  mov eax, edi
  sar eax, 31
  sar edx, 2
  sub edx, eax
  lea eax, [rdx+rdx*4]
  add eax, eax
  sub edi, eax
  test edx, edx
  lea eax, [rdi+rcx*2]
  mov edi, edx
  jne .L3
  rep ret
.L4:
  rep ret
```

as you see the compilers same good/better than the 99.99% of the coders

Comment: For your "fastest" version, looks like you forgot to tell gcc to optimize for a modern CPU; it's not taking advantage of macro-fusion.  Use `-mtune=haswell`, or better `-march=haswell`.  You could also get faster code if you used unsigned instead of signed division.  I don't think you want your remainder to be `-9..0` for negative inputs anyway.  But yes, [using `idiv` for constant divisors is well known to be sub-optimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183935/why-does-gcc-use-multiplication-by-a-strange-number-in-implementing-integer-divi)

Comment: @PeterCordes - in this example I do not see many possible improvements.

Comment: @PeterCordes OP wants signed to have the signed result

Comment: Ok, that's fair, I was thinking the algo would be broken with negative inputs, but it does actually work.  You do get `-321` from `-123` https://godbolt.org/g/u9rrru.  Still, for larger numbers it would be more efficient to handle the sign outside the loop, instead of doing extra work for signed division / modulo with the fixed-point multiplicative inverse.

Comment: The improvement you'd get from `-march=haswell` is putting the `test` right before the `jne`, saving 1 total uop.  Also removing the `rep` prefix from the `ret`, because we probably don't care about AMD K10.

Comment: @PeterCordes you are missing the point of my answer. I just wanted to show the OP that it is a complete waste of time writing this kind of code in the assembler.

Comment: Oh.  I thought it was a challenge to the 0.01% of coders to find the optimizations gcc missed, sorry. :P  I did notice the OP was zeroing `edx` (inefficiently), instead of `cdq`, so the OP either doesn't care about negative numbers, or else has another bug they haven't discovered yet.

Comment: I'm just getting started in asm so this was just an exercise to get used to the standard commands. I'm well aware that I can't beat the compiler.